# "wget --domains" not helping.. what am I doing wrong?

Tags: wget

I'm attempting to use wget to recursively grab only the .jpg files from a particular website, with a view to creating an amusing screensaver for myself. Not such a lofty goal really.

The problem is that the pictures are hosted elsewhere (mfrost.typepad.com), not on the main domain of the website (www.cuteoverload.com).

I have tried using "-D" to specified the allowed domains, but sadly no cute jpgs have been forthcoming. How could I alter the line below to make this work?

```
wget -r -l2 -np -w1 -D www.cuteoverload.com,mfrost.typepad.com -A.jpg -R.html.php.gif www.cuteoverload.com/
```

Thanks.

Comment: `-np` / `--no-parent` and `-D` / `--domains` didn't seemed to work for me, I had wget `1.12` installed, after installing wget `1.16` same command returned different result, the domains limitation works now. My full command included these additional options: `-m -E -k -np`.

Comment: My case required also -erobots=off. Files I wanted to download were excluded for robots.

Comment: Use https://www.httrack.com/, wget options are poor when you want to dl content which  is hosted on other domains and only linked on site you are crawling.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An examination of *wget*'s man page[1] says this about -D:

> Set domains to be followed.  domain-list is a comma-separated list of domains.  Note that it does not turn on -H.

This advisory about -H looks interesting:

> Enable spanning across hosts when doing recursive retrieving.

So you need merely to add the -H flag to your invocation.

(Having done this, looks like all the images are restricted to *mfrost.typepad.com/cute_overload/images/2008/12/07* and *mfrost.typepad.com/cute_overload/images/2008/12/08*).

--
[1] Although *wget*'s primary reference manual is in info format.